# How do I display my fetched MySQL data nicely into HTML on my webpage

Tags: php, html

I need to create a button that will be able to search for what is input by the user and display that information to the page and allow the customer to pay for their order.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Id</th></tr>";
class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
function __construct($it) {
parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
}

function current() {
return "<td style='width: 150px; border: 1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
}

function beginChildren() {
echo "<tr>";
}

function endChildren() {
echo "</tr>" . "\n";
}
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "i8127115_wp4";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT info FROM wp_amelia_customer_bookings");
$stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
    echo $v;
}
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why use RecursiveArrayIterator? Is it something you need? the code can be simplified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates a Table with your info and should be more resource-efficient.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>
<tr><th>Id</th></tr>
<?php
define('DB_ADR', 'localhost');
define('DB_DBN', 'i8127115_wp4');
define('DB_USR', '');
define('DB_PWD', '');
define('TMPL', '<tr><td style="width: 150px; border: 1px solid black;">%s</td></tr>');

try {
    $pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host='.DB_ADR.';dbname='.DB_DBN.';charset=UTF8', DB_USR, DB_PWD);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    foreach($pdo->query("SELECT info FROM wp_amelia_customer_bookings;") as $row) {
        print sprintf(TMPL, $row['title']);
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
</table></body></html>
```